# Partial and Total functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, partial-fractions

OK guys I have to find the number of partial and total functions $ f:A\rightarrow A  $ , where $ |A|=n $. The answers are respectively $ (n+1)^n $ and $ n^n $, but I just can't figure out how exactly we come to this conclusion. Could you please explain why this is so and the logic behind it ?

Comment: I suggest that you first work this out for small values of $n$. After doing this you might see how to construct an argument in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for each element of $A$ what it can be sent to under a function $f$ - how many options are there in each case?

Comment: Well for the total I get $ n^n $, because for every element n of the domain you can send it to n elements from the co domain. But i don't get partial functions.

Comment: Remember that for partial functions you also have the option of the function not being defined on that element...

Comment: Aha I get it thanks. :)